# Index of element in sorted()

Tags: swift, sorting

When you call

```
sorted(<#source: C#>, <#isOrderedBefore: (C.Generator.Element, C.Generator.Element) -> Bool##(C.Generator.Element, C.Generator.Element) -> Bool#>)
```

you can access the two source elements for comparison via `$0` and `$1`. But how can I determine the index from where they were taken from the source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass into `sorted` not a collection of elements, but the indices of the elements:

```
let a = ["hello","i","must","be","going"]
let idxs = sorted(indices(a)) { a[$0] < a[$1] }
// produces [3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
```

Or, if you don't like capturing `a` and wanted the elements themselves passed into the closure, you could pass in a sequence of pairs of the index and the element, like so:

```
let pairs = sorted(Zip2(indices(a),a)) {
    $0.1 < $1.1
}
```

Note the result would be an array of `(index,element)` pairs: `[(3, be), (4, going), (0, hello), (1, i), (2, must)]`.  If you wanted to turn that back into just the elements, you can do `map(pairs) { $0.1 }`

Also, if you take the just-indices route and want to turn that back into elements later, you can do it with `PermutationGenerator`:

```
let values = PermutationGenerator(elements: a, indices: idxs)
println(" ".join(values)) // prints "be going hello i must"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Maybe I'd guessed that since it's so trivial. But maybe not ;-)

Comment: As of Xcode 7.3, PermutationGenerator is marked as deprecated: *"PermitationGenerator will be removed in Swift 3"* (and the typo is not mine :)

Comment: Also mentioned here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md:  *"PermutationGenerator was removed."* – Do you know if  there some replacement?